# Why does remote: true and confirm: 'Are You Sure?' not work together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ujs

I have been wrestling with Rails 4 and UJS and noticed that Rails 4.1 doesn't behave (specifically, rails-ujs) the way I would expect.

When using a remote link with a confirmation dialog, the UJS driver sends the XHR before the confirmation popup is approved (making the confirmation popup pointless).  I would have expected Rails to be able to handle this combination of options, but I had to write my own javascript to perform the confirmation popup and hook onto the "ajax:beforeSend" event to prevent the request from firing too soon.

Here's what I had that did not work (request fired immediately, did not wait for confirm dialog to return true):

```
= link_to 'Ajax Button', app_path(resource), method: :delete, 
    remote: true, id: 'ajax_link', disable_with: 'Wait...',
    confirm: 'Are you sure?'
```

Here's what I have now that does work:

```
= link_to 'Ajax Button', app_path(resource), method: :delete,
    remote: true, id: 'ajax_link', disable_with: 'Wait...'

$ ->
  $("a[data-remote]#ajax_link").on 'ajax:beforeSend', (xhr, settings) ->
    return confirm("Are you sure?")
```

Is it just me or shouldn't rails/jquery-ujs handle the above combination of options and wait for the confirmation popup?  In the past, Rails 3 and prior, the remote links/buttons usually "just worked" when it came to AJAX and remote requests, but it seems with Rails 4 that working with AJAX requires a bit more finesse that was previously required.

Has anyone else experienced this with Rails 4.1?  Any other solutions out there?

Comment: Try `= link_to 'Ajax Button', app_path(resource), method: :delete, remote: true, id: 'ajax_link', data: { disable_with: "Wait..." },
data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }`.If it works i will post it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @pavan, thats definitely a thought.  The syntax I used is technically deprecated so I'll give your solution a go and see if that makes it work the way I expected.

Answer (score 11):

The below should work

```
= link_to 'Ajax Button', app_path(resource), method: :delete, remote: true, id: 'ajax_link', data: { disable_with: "Wait..." }, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

Comment: Any suggestion with regards to a `f.sumbit`? I feel like I'm experiencing the same behavior as the original question but have not been successful with this approach.

Comment: Perfect Answer!!

Comment: This should be rewrite:
```
= link_to 'Ajax Button', app_path(resource), method: :delete, remote: true, id: 'ajax_link', data: { disable_with: "wait...", confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```